# Find the value of $a$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

please help I'm lost on what numbers to add or what formula to use

Answer (score 3):

Use Pythagoras: $$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$

[Pythagorean theorem](http://www.mathsisfun.com/pythagoras.html)

$$a^2+12^2=20^2$$

$$a^2 + 144 = 400$$

Subtract 144 from both sides.

$$a^2 = 256$$

you only take the positive answer.

$$a = \sqrt{256}=16$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this post because I think that the animated gif on [Wikipedia's article on the Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) is really cool.

**hint**

$b=12$ and $c=20$

[image]